# Identity Server 4 (Asp.net core) - Redirect Uri Validation Questions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm looking to utilize a custom RedirectUriValidator.

I already have a class that implements the IRedirectUriValidator interface, and when I explicitly utilize my implementation (via Dependency Injection) it does exactly what it is supposed to.

However, it seems that Identity Server uses it's own default Redirect Validator (based on my research), yet I have not seen evidence of how nor where it does this validation.

If I manually change the `redirect_uri` in a query string (simulating a basic attack) to something such as https://google.com I am redirected to google after authentication. Which I do not want to happen.

I am manually using methods like `Redirect(redirect_uri)` where redirect_uri would be https://google.com in my example, which would make sense as to why the app redirects to whatever uri anyway, but I'm unsure of any alternatives.

Is there some Identity Server specific way to redirect to X redirect uri that passes it through a validator?

Second, I also see that we can use `AddRedirectUriValidator<MyRedirectValidator>()` and I still cannot see that this is working. My custom validator never seems to be called.

I've hit a wall in my research. I've perused google, stackoverflow, and the Identity Server 4 github for some clarification. I couldn't find much.

In my `startup.cs` I have this:

```
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddRedirectUriValidator<MyRedirectValidator>()
            ;
```

And I cannot ever see evidence of it working.

I've also done this:

`services.AddTransient<IRedirectUriValidator, MyRedirectValidator>();`

And if I pass that into a controller/razor page constructor and use it, it of course does what it is meant to.

```
public class MyRedirectValidator : IRedirectUriValidator
{
    public Task<bool> IsPostLogoutRedirectUriValidAsync(string requestedUri, Client client)
    {
        foreach (String uri in client.PostLogoutRedirectUris)
        {
            string pattern = string.Concat(@"^", uri);
            Match m = Regex.Match(requestedUri, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }

    public Task<bool> IsRedirectUriValidAsync(string requestedUri, Client client)
    {
        foreach (String  uri in client.RedirectUris)
        {
            string pattern = string.Concat(@"^", uri);
            Match m = Regex.Match(requestedUri, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (m.Success)
            {
          return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
```

}

So my overall question/issue has multiple parts that I'm having a tough time with.

1. At what point in a login/logout process would the default redirect uri validator be called? Does something like SignInManager call this internally?
2. Am I missing something in how to implement, utilize, and or debug the Redirect Uri Validation process for a custom validator?

Comment: Its only relevant in like implicit or auth code flows (or hybrid) so are you using one of those when you are testing?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Implicit and Client Credentials in terms of my Client configurations, if that's what you were asking?

Comment: Are you calling connect/token or connect/authorize when testing?

Comment: The default behaviour is that an authorize endpoint `redirect_url` will be validated and the whole request rejected if it's not in the list for the client so I'm not sure how you're getting into this situation. Can you provide an example of the flow where validation is not occurring maybe?

Comment: Also, out of interest, what custom behaviour are you looking to implement? I'd be wary of deviating from the "must match client exactly" default approach.

Comment: @mackie @VidmantasBlazevicius I may have figured out my issue.

So my whole ReturnUrl query parameter could be something like the following:

```ReturnUrl=/connect/authorize?
    client_id=client1&
    scope=openid email api1&
    response_type=id_token token&
    redirect_uri=https://google.com&
    state=abc&
    nonce=xyz```

If I use something like ```LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl)``` and I changed the redirect_uri to google, then I get our default developer error page.

Whereas, in some other situations we are parsing out the redirect_uri and then redirecting to that specifically

Comment: @mackie also, as for our custom validation logic, we were thinking of verifying only subdomain/domain.

For example we have ```https://ourdomain.com/signin-oidc``` as a redirect uri in the Client config stored in the DB, but we may want to redirect them somewhere like ```https://ourdomain.com/some/other/place``` or something like that.

As such we were thinking that if we verify the subdomain (if it exists in the uri) and the domain, we should be safe still.

That was the thought, at least.

Comment: @netdev19 just be aware that partial validation like that is a spec violation. OIDC mandates strict matching due to historical real-world vulnerabilities related to redirect-based authentication schemes that didn't do that. Proceed with caution and definitely use hybrid or code flows with PKCE if going that route.

Comment: RedirectUriValidator is to validate client redirect uris, not for redirects. :)

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794256/1098814 works?